# Angular 2 Style Guide Helper in Atom — Missing Feature

Tags: angular, typescript, atom-editor, angular2-styleguide

My supervisor has Atom with eight plugins for Angular. I have the same eight plugins installed. But I'm missing a feature that he has, and we're not sure what plugin or preferences will provide the feature. It is to do with the Angular 2 Style Guide. It provides information of code that doesn't meet the style guidelines.

You can see the warnings in this screenshot of the lower right of his IDE window:

[image]

Looking at the same file in my IDE, I see no warnings:

[image]

The plugins he and I have installed when I search for 'angular' are:

angular-2-typescript-snippets, angular-bootstrap, angular2-snippets, angular2-snippets-atom, angularjs, angular-helper, angularjs-snippets, angularjs-styleguide-snippets

One thing that may be different for us is that he is on a Linux system, and I am on Mac OS.

I need this feature. Can someone please help me figure out how to bring it to Atom for me?

Comment: I think this might be TSLint - that has a [import-spacing](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/import-spacing/) rule which would show such a warning - in that case it would most likely be the [linter-tslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-tslint) atom package

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you mean there's a TSLint package? I searched and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I added a link to the package i think it might be in my previous comment: https://atom.io/packages/linter-tslint You'll have to check with your supervisor (or just try it) to see if it is really this package you are missing

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: If you post your solution as an answer to this question, I'll vote it up and select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, as requested:

The warning message is produced by [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/). The corresponding package that adds support for Atom is **linter-tslint** which can be found under the following link: https://atom.io/packages/linter-tslint